How to update a value by time smoothly in React Native?
I am trying to make a smooth transition of a value (not a view), I mean setting its initial value to 0 and after 3000ms its value to 100, with a smooth increase by time. Same as in css transitions and easing methods, but in React Native. I will not use this value inside a view like Animated.View, I will use this value dynamically as given in the sample code. Is there a way to do this? Maybe in Skia? I am new in Skia library. I tried something like this but no luck:
import { useValue } from "@shopify/react-native-skia";
const verticalOffset = useValue(initialVerticalOffset)
const animatedValue = new Animated.Value(500)
useEffect(()=>{
   verticalOffset.current = animatedValue  // value must be number error
   Animated.timing(animatedValue, {toValue: 0, useNativeDriver: true, duration:3000}).start()
},[])

